# 'Evilsome': archaic or British?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, usage, archaic-language

Has anyone come across the word "Evilsome?" When I do a search on google, I also find this in older books from the late 1800s and early 1900s. But I see this commonly used by Asians even today. Many of my American friends find it simply fancy. Is this word British?

Example 1: "The Great texts of the Bible"
Edited by Rev. James Hastings D. D, year: 1912.
Section St. John XIII-XXI - Page 305

> **A lie is the root of all evilsome misconception or misunderstanding** .

Example 2: "The Feet of Jesus in Life, Death, Resurrection, and Glory - Page 87, Philip Bennett Power · 1872

> **Overstrained good may , however , become evilsome of the most subtle and best masked evil is nothing but this.[..]**

I can keep adding more examples if you like. A simple google search for the word "evilsome" in quotes fetches many examples of its occurrences in old books if you navigate to the Books category.

People have marked this question for closing. Maybe I should take this question elsewhere.

Comment: Please provide a link to one or more books that contain this word.

Comment: I have added couple of instances from two old books.

Comment: Unfortunately, the lines are misquoted. I found two online sources and for the first it says [*A lie is* **the root of all evil** — **some misconception** *or misunderstanding*.](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/hastings/john/17-19.htm)  The second, [*Overstrained good may, however*, **become evil. Some of the** *most subtle and best masked evil* — *is nothing but this*…](https://www.gracegems.org/Power/feet_of_jesus1.htm)

Comment: Google Books will provide snippets of text where the dash is misinterpreted by the software. Exactly as Katy explained in their answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not a standard English word, either British or American. All the results I'm seeing on Google ngrams are false positives due to a machine failure to recognize punctuation.

Most are failures to distinguish between an em-dash separating words rather than a dash marking a word split across two lines.

Some are a failure to register the end of one sentence and the beginning of another.

The only corpus I see this used in as a word is the Indian English corpus.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be in the OED, Cambridge dictionaries online, or Merriam-Webster either (but I assume the OP already checked some dictionaries). Probably best to avoid.

Comment: It is not in the corpora I checked (NOW, iWeb, BNC, or COCA) with the exception of a single instance in GloWBe, from Jamaica.

Comment: @Katy Thank you. Yes, many Indian writers use it as a standard word to explain something which is fearful and evil. Like @ Stuart F said, probably best to avoid.

Comment: @Ammu You're welcome. A quick tip: when using the search function on Google books, especially with older texts, it's good to click through the result. Usually it will take you to the actual page that the bot is reading, and you will be able to see the punctuation (and the mistakes the machine is making) for yourself rather than relying on the quote the machine pulls up.

Comment: @Katy That's where I failed. I will do it from now on.